# TensorFlow ValueError: Dimensions must be equal

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

My features are 4000-dimensional `float32` vectors, my labels are 8000-dimensional `float32` vectors. I'm evidently getting a dimensions mismatch when I try to train my model, but I can't see where.

```py
def get_audio_samples_as_tensor(filepath, num_desired_samples=-1):
  audio_binary = tf.io.read_file(filepath) # Decodes a 16-bit PCM WAV file to a float32 tensor.
  tensor, number_of_samples = tf.audio.decode_wav(audio_binary, desired_samples=num_desired_samples)
  tensor = tf.squeeze(tensor, axis=-1) # remove last dimension (representing number of channels). Resulting shape: (None,)
  return tensor

def get_truth_and_labelled_tensors(filename):
  truth_filepath = tf.convert_to_tensor(TRUTH_DIR) + os.sep + filename
  labelled_filepath = tf.convert_to_tensor(DOWNSCALED_DIR) + os.sep + filename

  truth_audio_samples_tensor = get_audio_samples_as_tensor(truth_filepath, num_desired_samples=8000)
  labelled_audio_samples_tensor = get_audio_samples_as_tensor(labelled_filepath, num_desired_samples=4000)
  print("truth_audio_samples_tensor shape: ", truth_audio_samples_tensor.shape) # (8000,)
  print("labelled_audio_samples_tensor shape: ", labelled_audio_samples_tensor.shape) # (4000,)
  
  return labelled_audio_samples_tensor, truth_audio_samples_tensor

train_filenames_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_filenames)
train_waveforms_ds = train_filenames_ds.map(get_truth_and_labelled_tensors, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

validation_filenames_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(validation_filenames)
validation_waveforms_ds = validation_filenames_ds.map(get_truth_and_labelled_tensors, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

model = models.Sequential([
  layers.Input(shape=(4000,1)),
  layers.Dense(units=8000),
])

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_waveforms_ds,
                    validation_data=validation_waveforms_ds,
                    epochs=10)
```

````
Epoch 1/10
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 4000, 1) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 4000, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_17'), name='input_17', description="created by layer 'input_17'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (4000, 1, 1).
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 8000 and 4000 for '{{node Equal}} = Equal[T=DT_FLOAT, incompatible_shape_error=true](ExpandDims_1, Cast_1)' with input shapes: [8000,1], [4000,1].```
````

Answer (score 0):

You will have to reshape your tensor's as shown below.

```
labelled_audio_samples_tensor = tf.reshape(labelled_audio_samples_tensor , [batch_size, 4000, 1] 

truth_audio_samples_tensor = tf.reshape(truth_audio_samples_tensor, [batch_size, 8000]
```

**Update after the comment:**

If that is the case, could you apply `tf.expand_dims` to reshape your tensor as shown below?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that produces the following error: `ValueError: Cannot reshape a tensor with 8000 elements to shape [5,8000] (40000 elements) for '{{node Reshape}} = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32](Squeeze, Reshape/shape)' with input shapes: [8000], [2] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [5,8000].` I've tried with other values for `batch_size` but I still get that error.. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Eric sorry for the late reply, I have updated my answer, could you try to apply that and let me know what was the result?